# How to get hour by hour data in sql server (specific with minutes)

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to get hour by hour data (no matter what is the date) in sql server, I know it can be achieved with datePart(hour, columnname) but to be specific, I need data for specific intervals including minutes regardless of dates.

Scenario: 'TestTable' contains column - DBTimestamp with data type (DateTime)

I need all Records from 'TestTable' for which 'DBTimestamp' is between 3 Hours 35 Minutes And 4 Hours 30 Minutes regardless of date specified.

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on?  Can you include your code?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Something like a simple select like this? 
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE CAST(DBTimestamp as TIME) BETWEEN '03:35' and '04:30'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you need records that in specific range of time regardless of date part. So I've come up with following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id, CAST(Time AS time) [time]
FROM Table) AS Q1
WHERE Q1.time > CAST('03:35:00' AS time)
AND Q1.time < CAST('12:30:00' AS time)
```

Here is SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21b313/1

Comment: The answer and SQLFiddle are not the same query. The SQLFiddle is exactly Serkan Arslans answer. Also the time is wrong. 12:30 instead of 04:30. And also you need to change to >= from > and to <= from < to avoid missing some entries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this.

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE CAST(DBTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '03:35' AND '04:30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you could do some variation of the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR, TIMESTAMP) = 3 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, TIMESTAMP) >= 35) OR
      (DATEPART(HOUR, TIMESTAMP) = 4 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, TIMESTAMP) <= 30)
```